# Error while installing program

Tags: installshield

I got the following error message during the installation of the program :
"1: ALLUSERS property is not 1 - this MSM cannot be used for a per-user or fallback-to-user install 2: 2"
Binaries for installation were compiled by Install Shield v 12.

Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Your setup program includes a [merge module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369820%28VS.85%29.aspx) that only supports machine-wide installations. If your program contains the installation scope dialog box (Install for: All users on this computer / Just for me), select the first option. If it doesn't, run it from the command line using:

```
msiexec /i YourSetup.msi ALLUSERS=1
```